# Launcher activity instance restarts when widget configuration activity closes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, widget, android-pendingintent

I have an activity A which can be used to configure a widget. But it can be also directly started from the launcher. The launcher instance gets restarted when a widget configuration instance is saved. I wonder why.

First I start the activity from the launcher. Then I press the Home button so that the activity is stopped.

Now I click on an widget on the home screen and the widget configuration activity instance starts. This is how I call it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, A.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

When leaving the widget configuration activity instance e.g. through a save button click the launcher activity instance gets restarted.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        settings.save();

        // Signal that saving was performed and widget should be shown
        Intent resultValue = new Intent();
        resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);

        BreakWidgetProvider.updateWidgets(new int[] { appWidgetId }, this);

        this.finish();
    }
```

The activities should belong to different tasks. I wonder why they are related.

How can I prevent the restart of the launcher activity instance?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
It seems the widget configuration activity instance got child of the the one started by the launcher. So I adjusted the manifest like below.

```
<activity
    android:name=".BreakMainActivity"            
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="standard"
    **android:allowTaskReparenting="false"**
    **android:noHistory="true"**            
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I suppose allowTaskReparenting="false" would have been enough.